# How to preview merge field information?

Tags: c#, properties, office-interop, cpu-word

I have a code that opens up a word document, reads an excel file as data source for mail merge fields, and then saves the document.

The problem: I want the text in the merge field to be shown (and saved) as "previewed". (e.g. the field shows its value lets say "Dog" instead of its field title  "Animal"). In the Word application i would simply click the button "Preview Result".

By recording a macro I have found that this can be solved in Visual Basic by the line `ActiveDocument.MailMerge.ViewMailMergeFieldCodes = wdToggle`
although I have not managed to use this in the C#-code.

I am new in both coding and this forum, so please let me know if I can provide more information.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Office.Core;

namespace word
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        
        private void CreateWordDocument(object wordFilename, object excelSource)
        {
            Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
            object missing = Missing.Value;
            Word.Document myWordDoc = null;

            object readOnly = false;
            object isVisible = false;
            wordApp.Visible = true;

            myWordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref wordFilename, ref missing, ref readOnly,
                                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
            myWordDoc.Activate();

            myWordDoc.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = 
            Word.WdMailMergeMainDocType.wdNotAMergeDocument; 
            myWordDoc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource(Name: excelSource, Format: ref missing,  
            SQLStatement: "SELECT*FROM`Data$`");

            //Any code for previewing
            //VB-code: ActiveDocument.MailMerge.ViewMailMergeFieldCodes = wdToggle

            myWordDoc.SaveAs2(ref wordFilename, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                           ref mailmerge, ref missing, ref missing,
                           ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                           ref missing);

            myWordDoc.Close();
            wordApp.Quit();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The property to use is:

```
myWordDoc.ActiveWindow.View.MailMergeDataView = true;
```

Read more here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.view.mailmergedataview?view=word-pia